# Using Map Snapshots With Widgets

Tags: android, google-maps, widget

I am developing a Google Maps application as the Capstone project for my Android Developer Nanodegree through Udacity, and have come across an issue that I am not sure how to address.

I am required to include a widget in the application, but since widgets don't support MapViews I would like to take snapshots (i.e. create bitmaps) of the user's favorite locations and use ImageViews to display them in the widget.

In order to create the snapshot, I have to use GoogleMap to render the location and the SnapshotReadyCallback to retrieve the rendered image to store and then pass to the widget.  Since the GoogleMap class can only run on the main UI thread, I can't do this rendering from the widget or the backend service.  I could do it from the Favorites page (which renders a list of Lite-style maps), but the user isn't obligated to visit the Favorites page before using the widget.  And I can't really take a snapshot when the user selects a favorite location because the main map can have many markers at any one time and it would be awkward if I removed the markers, took the snapshot, and then re-rendered the map.

Is there any way I can take a snapshot off the main thread?  Is there any way I can display a MapView from within a widget?  Or is there some other meaningful widget that would be useful for a map application?  I really don't want to display a textual list of named coordinates.

I have read that it's possible to use online Google services to return images -- and I may consider this if I've exhausted every other option.  But I'd really like to keep the functionality in-house if possible.

Thanks for your time.

Darryl

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous post everyone -- within a minute after posting my question, a realistic solution came to mind.  When the user selects a favorite location, I could display a confirmation dialog with a map of the location on it, and use the occasion to take a snapshot.  I am still open to other suggestions.

Darryl